# Clevo X7200 - SLI 485M With or without additional AC Adapter & Power Converter Box?

Tags: laptop

I've been getting conflicting answers.

Some say that the Additional AC Adapter is a necessity to exert the laptop to its fullest extent and that you plug in both adapters simultaneously, whereas others say it's not a necessity at all. I called Sager, a tech guy told me that with the i7 960 cpu I would not need the additional Adapter.

Can somebody please clarify this for me?

Do I really need the additional AC Adapter or not?

Answer (score 1):

You better do. At fully loaded, 960 consumes 130W and 485M sli consume 100W each. Which need 330W in total already. No mention other power comsuming from other staff like fans, usb devices you plug in those usb ports.

You may be fine working with only a 300W PSU. But your laptop may shutdown when it is fully loaded due to the lack of power supply.